# Forcing function in R ODE gives error (number of derivatives)

Tags: r, ode, forcing

I want to use R to solve two ODEs of a boxmodell. I want to use a forcing function to vary the input parameter cw with time t. This works when I only use a boxmodell with two boxes:

```
dCs<-function(t, y, parms){
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    dCs<-k3*cw(t)-k4*cs
    return(list(dCs, dCw=cw(t)))
  })
}
```

But when I change the function to add another box as follows I get an error:

```
dCs<-function(t, y, parms){
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    dCp<-(k1*cw(t)-(k2+k3)*cp+k4*cs)
    dCs<-(k3*cp-k4*cs)
    list(dCw=cw(t), dCs, dCp)
  })
}

Fehler in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : 
  The number of derivatives returned by func() (1) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (2)
```

I doublechecked with the following answer to the same error, but it does not work for me. As far as I can see all parameters are labeled correctly:
[Difficulty running an ODE model in R including a parameter that varies by time (forcing function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379901/difficulty-running-an-ode-model-in-r-including-a-parameter-that-varies-by-time?rq=1)

```
#modelled time
times<-seq(0,56)

#input parameters
parms<-c(k1=0.1,
         k2=0.01,
         k3=0.1,
         k4=0.01)

#initial values
y0<-c(cs = 0,
      cp = 0)

#linear interpolation of concentration cw
flux<-data.frame(time = c(10,12, 17,1,2,14,3,21,4,28,5,35,6,42,7,49,8,56),
                 cw = c(48,61,62,32,65,71,95,71,65,67,48,66,81,71,64,91,87,67))
cw<-approxfun(x = flux[,1], y = flux[,2], method = "linear", rule = 2)

out1<-ode(times = times, func = dCs, y = y0 , parms = parms)
```

How can I correct the inital conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution allows to add two independent variables to an ode. The output only contains time as a dependent variables, however it corresponds to the second independent variable cw.

```
#model
model<-function(time, y, parms, ...){
  with(as.list(c(parms, y)), {
    dCp<-(k1*cw(time)-k2*cp-k3*cp+k4*cs)
    dCs<-(k3*cp-k4*cs)
    list(c(dCp, dCs))
  })
}
#cost function
cost.model <- function(p) {
  out  <-  ode(y0, times, model, p, method="rk4")
  modCost(out, dat, y="value")
}

#independent variable times
times<-seq(0,56)

#independent variable cw
flux<-df.i[df.i$Samp=="CC",c(2,9)]
flux<-flux[!duplicated(flux$time),]
#interpolation of cw
cw<-approxfun(x = flux[,1], y = flux[,2], method = "linear", rule = 2)
#initial values
y0<-c(cp=0,
      cs=0)

#parameters
parms<-c(k1=0.1,
         k2=0.1,
         k3=0.1,
         k4=0.001)

#fit
dat<-df.i
fit<-modFit(f=cost.mod, p=parms)
```

for `cw` data are extracted from the dataframe `df.i` and interpolated to give values for every value of `times`. `df.i` is modulated so it fits to the call of the cost function (not shown) which is then executed.